# ADO.NET Error: inserts duplicate records on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

This is weird. I have this POS winform app that connects to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database through ADO.NET. It works fine, saving thousands of records every day, but I noticed a strange behavior: When the client machine hangs for any reason when saving the record and then it reboots, the next time my app runs, it resends the previous dataset to the DB, even twice, resulting in a duplicate sales entry. I guess the ADO.NET layer keeps the transaction as not saved despite it was saved.

```
public int UpdateVentas(dsetVentas ds)
    {
        Int32 _newId = 0;
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        SqlDataAdapter daDetalle = null;
        SqlDataAdapter daPagos = null;
        using (TransactionScope scope = Utils.GetTransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                //tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
                // prepare adapters
                da = getDA2updateVentas(conn);
                daDetalle = getDA2updateVentasDetalle(conn);
                daPagos = getDA2updatePagos(conn);
                // prepare table of deleted, added and modified details
                DataTable DeletedDetalle = ds.VentasDetalle.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
                DataTable AddedDetalle = ds.VentasDetalle.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                DataTable ModifiedDetalle = ds.VentasDetalle.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);

                // payments
                DataTable DeletedPagos = ds.Pagos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
                DataTable AddedPagos = ds.Pagos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                DataTable ModifiedPagos = ds.Pagos.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);

                // execute in proper order

                // deleted rows
                if ((DeletedDetalle != null))
                {
                    daDetalle.Update(DeletedDetalle);
                }
                if (DeletedPagos != null)
                {
                    daPagos.Update(DeletedPagos);
                }

                // save main record
                // ///////////////////////////////////
                //
                da.Update(ds, "Ventas");
                //
                // ///////////////////////////////////
                // gets new ID
                //dsetVentas.VentasRow r = (dsetVentas.VentasRow)ds.Ventas.Rows[0]; //_newId = r.IdVenta;
                _newId = ds.Ventas[0].IdVenta;
                // updates details & payments
                if ((ModifiedDetalle != null))
                {
                    daDetalle.Update(ModifiedDetalle);
                }
                if (ModifiedPagos != null)
                {
                    daPagos.Update(ModifiedPagos);
                }

                // inserts details & payments
                if ((AddedDetalle != null))
                {
                    foreach (dsetVentas.VentasDetalleRow detalle in AddedDetalle.Rows)
                    {
                        detalle.IdVenta = _newId;
                    }
                    daDetalle.Update(AddedDetalle);
                }

                if (AddedPagos != null)
                {
                    foreach (dsetVentas.PagosRow pago in AddedPagos.Rows)
                    {
                        pago.IdDocumento = _newId;
                    }
                    daPagos.Update(AddedPagos);
                }
                scope.Complete();
                ds.AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                _newId = 0;
                _ErrorMessage = ex1.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        da = null;
        return _newId;
    }
```

Comment: Where does the `conn` variable coming from? A private variable? Would it really hurt application performance to use it as a local variable inside a `using` block? The `conn` object persisting between calls to the method might be the culprit.

Comment: Irrespective of how good or bad an application is coded,  the RAM is wiped out on each system boot. So unless the data has been saved to a persistent medium it will be lost. This is just commonsense. So you might be looking at the wrong code as culprit.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, you're absolutely right. I guess the culprit lies in the SQL Server engine, but I cannot figure out how to catch it. I've checked the SQL error log, but there's no info available. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: UPDATE: Today, the user gave a hint. After the machine crashed, she rebooted and the printer gave her the ticket with the duplicate entry. That means the app saved the data to the server BEFORE Windows hanged, but the ticket remained in the printer queue.

Comment: Hi @Greg, the `conn` variable is declared at the class level, it is initialized once by the form that completes the sale. If the sale is saved (I mean, no error messages returned) the form is closed and disposed, so are its objects. Besides that, the connection is opened and closed in the same method. On which line should I make the changes you suggest? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: So maybe the ticket remaining in the printer queue is the problem to solve? It could be that you are seeing duplicate entries because people are reentering the ticket information after rebooting a non responsive machine. Do you know why the machine hangs? Really that's the problem.

Comment: The extra tickets in the queue are not the problem, but the symptom. That means that ADO is sending the data repeatedly (with a difference of a second), it's not user's fault.